# Half screen view , iOS Sidebar Menu

Tags: iphone, ios6

As I want to display number of menus on a left side of a screen just like following-it is a new Facebook application.when you click on bar shown as a red square around it,the list view on a left side comes into picture after sliding a right part in my application is there any sdk is available to add this.Please help me.

[image]

Comment: if possible , edit your question title and put words as "Sliding menu for iOS"  because others are going to search by this title contents in their query, it will help them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just have a look

https://github.com/BenHall/ios_facebook_style_navigation

you will find many ways to do that.  Select anyone as per your need.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook guys have done brilliant job in the new version of the app. The similar open source code can be found from [here](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo) -

It reveals technique behind doing split view for iPhone.

Edit: Few other open source codes:

[Source 1](https://github.com/jeremieweldin/JWSlideMenu)
[Source 2](https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController)
[Source 3](https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController)
[Source 4](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck)
[Source 5](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController)
[Source 6](https://github.com/meiwin/MWFSlideNavigationViewController)
[Source 7](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu)
[Source 8](https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu)
[Source 9](https://github.com/gloubibou/HHTabListController)
[Source 10](https://github.com/myell0w/MTSlideViewController)
[Source 11](https://github.com/andrewroycarter/SlideViewController)

Answer (score 3):

NO there are no SDK available to do this.
you can do this by two way.

1. By using two UIViewController
2. By using two UIView.

I recommend second one because I have used it and working fine.

For first approach you will find some example and demo on github.com.

let me give you short idea how I have implemented it by using two UIView.

Your all normal content will be in default UIView and slide controls will be on second view.

By default normal UIView will be visible and slider UIView be at -x pos something like (-200,0,200,320)
set this according to your need.

When you click show/hide button it change its frame property so normal UIView slide right side 200 pt
and slider UIView come in screen.

Let me show u some code to hide/unhide:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
view.frame = CGRectMake(250,
           view.frame.origin.y,
           view.frame.size.width,
           view.frame.size.height);;

slideView.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.frame.origin.y, 250, view.frame.size.height);;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Parameter in CGRectMake can be anything according to what you want.

To implement this make a subclass of UIView. and add UITableView if u want look like facebook.

**Update:**

While searching some new implementation I found a wonderful job on this concept by one developer. If anyone is thinking to add this feature than you must visit this once :
[MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)

All the best

Comment: This actually works even in case you just want to have the second view slide above the maine view with a certain transparency. Good easy work-arroud.

Comment: hi @CRDave, I am trying to implement such behaviour.Can you help me out in this regard

Comment: I like to do help but before that visit this library. He hase done very grate job on this concept. I have implemented this in my new project and work very good. https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

Comment: I saw this @CRDave, but my problem is that, I want it on two UIViewControllers. First on my RootTableViewController and secondly when I click on any of the cells it goes to seconfTableViewController. here also I want to show a left button which will reveal the sideBar. How to do this.

Comment: You can add on any ViewController u want. I have implemented it when I need it in about 5-6 ViewController in a app.

Comment: but in the link you provided. it says that, we have to first declare what left right  and center viewControllers will be in appldelegate.m.So how I can later change that on navigation

Comment: No it is not require to define in appldelegate only. We require to make three object whenever you show new viewcontroller.

Comment: How u open new viewcontroller?

Comment: @CRDave from my RootTableViewController whnever I click any cell, I push the newController to the navigationController

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31709/discussion-between-ranjit-and-crdave)

Comment: @CRDave: Can you PLEAAASE build a short example(or a make a video) of how using that library? I tried following official manual/example but did not achieve making a side menu. Can you please?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [InteractiveSideMenu](https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu) library. It supports interactive opening/closing menu. 
It supports interactive opening/closing menu and following customization:

- Animation duration
- Visible content width
- Content scale
- Using spring animation with params customization
- Animation options like animation curve

You should use 3 basic ViewControllers for creating subclasses for implementing your side menu.

- `MenuContainerViewController` is a host for menu and content views
- `MenuViewController` is a container for menu view
- `MenuItemContentControlller` is a container for content that corresponds menu item

To setup your side menu you shoud do 3 things:

- Provide implementation of base `MenuViewController` and assing it to `menuViewController` property
- Provide implementation of menu content and assing array of content controllers to `contentViewControllers` property
- Select initial content controller by calling `selectContentViewController(_ selectedContentVC: MenuItemContentViewController)`

Here is an example of setup Host controller.

```
import InteractiveSideMenu

class HostViewController: MenuContainerViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.menuViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationMenu") as! MenuViewController

        self.contentViewControllers = contentControllers()

        self.selectContentViewController(contentViewControllers.first!)
    }

    private func contentControllers() -> [MenuItemContentViewController] {
        //here is instantiation of content view controllers
    }
}
```

You can find more details in the example [here](https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu/tree/master/Sample/Sample).

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is good and simple example for implement it]

Click following link to get it https://github.com/nverinaud/NVSlideMenuController