# swift 3 table view with slide out menu

Tags: swift, uitableview

I got problem with making table view on the same view with slide menu, could you help me how to do that, I created view controller and embeded navigation controller, now I just want add table vie behind the slide menu and show table view with two section and show data with one custom cell.

[image]

Comment: Please search the google as `Side menu in ios` there are tons of tutorials about it. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=sidemenu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Half screen view , iOS Sidebar Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352342/half-screen-view-ios-sidebar-menu)

Comment: Check out [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) and here is [an useful tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) about how to use that, and [Side Menu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) should help you as well

Answer (score 1):

@Egle Matutyte, I am supposing that you have done all work except SlideBar. 
I am providing code for SlideBar. Just add and try.

First Add the SideBar class i.e. below without any change

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol SideBarDelegate{
    func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(_ index:Int)
    @objc optional func sideBarWillClose()
    @objc optional func sideBarWillOpen()
}

class SideBar: NSObject, SideBarTableViewControllerDelegate {

    let barWidth:CGFloat = 150.0
    let sideBarTableViewTopInset:CGFloat = 64.0
    let sideBarContainerView:UIView = UIView()
    let sideBarTableViewController:SideBarTableViewController =       SideBarTableViewController()
    var originView:UIView = UIView()

    var animator:UIDynamicAnimator!
    var delegate:SideBarDelegate?
    var isSideBarOpen:Bool = false

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>){
        super.init()
        originView = sourceView
        sideBarTableViewController.tableData = menuItems

        setupSideBar()

        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: originView)

        let showGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SideBar.handleSwipe(_:)))
        showGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
        originView.addGestureRecognizer(showGestureRecognizer)

        let hideGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SideBar.handleSwipe(_:)))
        hideGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
        originView.addGestureRecognizer(hideGestureRecognizer)
    }


    func setupSideBar(){
        //sideBarContainerView.frame = CGRect(x: -barWidth - 1, y: originView.frame.origin.y, width: barWidth, height: originView.frame.size.height)

        sideBarContainerView.frame = CGRect(x: -barWidth - 1, y: sideBarTableViewTopInset, width: barWidth, height: originView.frame.size.height)

        sideBarContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        sideBarContainerView.clipsToBounds = false

        originView.addSubview(sideBarContainerView)

        let blurView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light))
        blurView.frame = sideBarContainerView.bounds
        sideBarContainerView.addSubview(blurView)


        sideBarTableViewController.delegate = self
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.frame = sideBarContainerView.bounds
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.clipsToBounds = false
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.scrollsToTop  = false
        //sideBarTableViewController.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(sideBarTableViewTopInset, 0, 0, 0)
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 0, 0, 0)
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.reloadData()

        sideBarContainerView.addSubview(sideBarTableViewController.tableView)
    }


    func handleSwipe(_ recognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        if recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left{
            showSideBar(false)
            delegate?.sideBarWillClose?()
        }else{
            showSideBar(true)
            delegate?.sideBarWillOpen?()
        }
    }


    func showSideBar(_ shouldOpen:Bool){
        animator.removeAllBehaviors()
        isSideBarOpen = shouldOpen

        let gravityX:CGFloat = (shouldOpen) ? 0.5 : -0.5
        let magnitude:CGFloat = (shouldOpen) ? 20 : -20
        let boundaryX:CGFloat = (shouldOpen) ? barWidth : -barWidth - 1


        let gravityBehavior:UIGravityBehavior = UIGravityBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView])
        gravityBehavior.gravityDirection = CGVector(dx: gravityX, dy: 0)
        animator.addBehavior(gravityBehavior)

        let collisionBehavior:UICollisionBehavior = UICollisionBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView])
        collisionBehavior.addBoundary(withIdentifier: "sideBarBoundary" as NSCopying, from: CGPoint(x: boundaryX, y: 20), to: CGPoint(x: boundaryX, y: originView.frame.size.height))
        animator.addBehavior(collisionBehavior)

        let pushBehavior:UIPushBehavior = UIPushBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView], mode: UIPushBehaviorMode.instantaneous)
        pushBehavior.magnitude = magnitude
        animator.addBehavior(pushBehavior)


        let sideBarBehavior:UIDynamicItemBehavior = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView])
        sideBarBehavior.elasticity = 0.3
        animator.addBehavior(sideBarBehavior)
    }

    func sideBarControlDidSelectRow(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        showSideBar(false)
    }
}
```

After this, add a new swift class

```
SideBarTableViewController
```

which inherit UITableViewController

```
import UIKit

protocol SideBarTableViewControllerDelegate{
    func sideBarControlDidSelectRow(_ indexPath:IndexPath)
}

class SideBarTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var delegate:SideBarTableViewControllerDelegate?
    var tableData:Array<String> = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkText

            let selectedView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell!.frame.size.width, height: cell!.frame.size.height))
            selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.3)

            cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
        }

        cell!.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 45
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.sideBarControlDidSelectRow(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Now paste the code below in your TableViewController or the page on which you want to add SlideBar.

let the name of your page is Dashboard, add the delegate as below

```
class Dashboard: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate
{
  //declare sidebar
    var sideBar:SideBar = SideBar()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        //Initialise the content of SlideBar Row
        sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, menuItems: ["Home", "Dashboard"])
        sideBar.delegate = self
    }

    func sideBarControlDidSelectRow(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected from SlideBar")
    }

    func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(_ index: Int)
    {
        //
    }
    //Add a button(Optional)in ViewDidLoad()
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         let btn_Hamburger = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 70,    width: 100, height: 25))
         btn_Hamburger.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btn_hamburger(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
         //add Image on Hamburger button
         btn_Hamburger.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "img_hemberger"), for: .normal)
         view.addSubview(btn_Hamburger)
    }
     //To in and out SideBar menu
    var flag:Bool = true
    func btn_hamburger(sender: UIButton!)
    {
        if flag == true {
            sideBar.showSideBar(true)
            flag = false
        }
        else{
            sideBar.showSideBar(false)
            flag = true
        }
    }
}
```